# seeElement doesnt find object even tho it is there

Tags: php, automation, codeception

I have this bit of code:

```
        $I->wait(2);
        $I->amOnPage('/ASTechOLE/exam-form-ng.php');
        $I->wait(2);


        $I->seeElement("//*[@id='oleWaitMessage']");
```

My problem is that it's giving me an error saying that it doesn't find the object but it actually is on the page.

I'm not sure (that's why I'm asking) but I think it may be something about the sessions? Before getting to that point, my code logs in, but this part doesn't actually give me any errors and goes as expected. Does codeception keep the session alive through the script?

This is the error:

```
1) FirstCest: Login successfully
 Test  tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:loginSuccessfully
 Step  See element "//*[@id='oleWaitMessage']"
 Fail  Element located either by name, CSS or XPath element with '//*[@id='oleWaitMessage']' was not found.

Scenario Steps:

 12. $I->seeElement("//*[@id='oleWaitMessage']") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:34
 11. $I->amOnPage("/ASTechOLE/exam-form-ng.php") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:30
 10. $I->click("Proceed") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:26
 9. $I->click("Proceed") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:24
 8. $I->click("Proceed") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:21
 7. $I->click("Proceed") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:19


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use PhpBrowser or WebDriver? PhpBrowser does not execute javascript code.

Comment: I use PhpBrowser. Sorry, I'm new to codeception, but why would that matter in this case?

Comment: If some content is generated by client-side Javascript code, PhpBrowser can't see it.
Disable Javascript in your browser and check if your page is rendered properly.